# Brake scrolling once it has started

Tags: javascript, scroll, touch, gestures, preventdefault

I need to programatically interrupt (brake) native free scrolling behaviour on mobile devices, very similar to what happens if you touch the screen (stops any free scrolling dead). The idea is to allow native scrolling and rubber banding as much as possible, until the 'scrollTop' reaches a desired element and then stop (snap) to that element.

I can get snapping working on swipe, but in order to make it work I have to 'disable' touchmove events by e.preventDefault(). Otherwise the 2 behaviours clash.

I want to try and avoid writing my own 'takeover' of the natural scrolling behaviour.

I have tried to trigger a 'touchstart' event to simulate the effect of braking it manually, but with no effect.

What is the best approach?